# Struct - How to change element in structure C

Tags: c, struct

We got a program and it holds 6 students we specified them at the beginning.
And the problem is i know how to print them in command line.
But how to edit them?
How to add more so we will have 7 students?
I also need to delete that student but teacher told me it would be good if its just empty space or Null.

```
 typedef struct Student{
    int NrAlbumu;
    char Imie[20];
    char Nazwisko[20];
    int RokStudiow;
    char Plec[20];
    char Zaleglosci[20];
}s;
```

Lets say its my struct.

Comment: You can't change a structure in C during runtime. Does your code needs to use a struct or this is just your idea ? Because you could use an array in two dimensions (char **students or char *students[100]) for this matter.

Comment: Well its not my idea, my teacher give me that task. 
1. I need to use struct
2. where the char *students[100] would be inside Student struct?

Comment: If you need to use a struct, you should follow the answer from @Kerasiotis loannis then !

Comment: If you need 7 structs, then make the simple array `struct Student students[7]`.  And drop the typedef until you understand things better.  Until then it will just cause confusion.

Comment: Could you show us how your code "holds 6 elements"? Is it declared as an array? Or allocated through malloc?

Comment: im not that advanced to answer your question @RobertoCaboni i dont know what malloc is.

Comment: I deleted what is in question and tries now with struct below.

Comment: Teachers comment implies that they expect you to use an array. Are you aware of the concepts of an array of structs?

Comment: No im not. But if i have array of 7 struct how i can access for example student no.1..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you done something different than the statement. I think you should use a Linked List Data Structure so you need have a struct like this.

```
typedef struct Student{
   char name[20];
   struct Student *next;
}s;
```

In order to make a list of them. You can take a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/)(it use int as data, so you must use string).

Feel free to ask me more!

Comment: It lets me have dynamic structure but how i can create student for example with index 1 and 2 and 3

Comment: you can add to struct another field called index. it is easy. before char name[20], add the line `int index;`.

Comment: How i can create Student with index 1 and Name Gabriel?

    scanf("%d", &s.index);
    printf("%d", s.index);

for index its not working

Comment: you should have a counter. Initialize an integer to zero (`int cnt=0;`) and after scanf, set the value `s.index=c++`.

Comment: it gives me still unexpected  expression in      `scanf("%d", &s.index);`

here is full code for now expect struct before int main():

`int main()
{
    int cnt=0;
    scanf("%d", &s.index);
    s.index=c++;
    printf("%d", s.index);
    return 0;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Array indexing could be dynamic as per program logic. This example just shows a way to add\remove student.

```
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 50

typedef struct {
     char *name;
     //add other student attributes
}student;   
    

student s[100]; //allocate array of students
//allocate memory for a student and add a student to the array
s[0].name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* MAX_NAME_LENGTH);
strcpy(s[0].name, "student1"); //student name could come from input

//deallocate memory for student and delete the student from array
free(s[0].name);
s[0].name = NULL;
```